# Module value is not being updated

Tags: angularjs, variables

I have a value defined in a module which I change in one controller. The problem is that the value is not updated in the other controller.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.value('value', 0);

app.controller('AdditionController', [
  'value',
  function (value) {
    this.add = function (ammount) {
      console.log('Value was equal to ' + value);
      value += ammount;
      console.log('Value no equals to ' + value);
    };
  }
]);

app.controller('PrintingController', [
  'value',
  function (value) {
    this.print = function () {
      console.log('Printer thinks that the value equals ' + value);
    };
  }
]);
```

The value is being changed only from the point of view of the first controller and not the second one. How can I force the value to be updated in the second controller? Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swxrd4bc/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `value` is typeof `number` which is a primitive type.

Primitive Type like string, boolean, number are all `pass by value`, which means the variable value will get copy and passed but not the reference(i.e. pointer).

To solve your problem, you should change `value`'s type from number to object

```
app.value('value', {val: 0});
```

Here is a working JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/3puss60r/

Whenever you face the problem that value does not update, think about the type, object and array are both passed by reference.

Comment: So there's no native way to pass a number by reference to the controller?

Comment: number itself is primitive type, primitive type in any language will be passed by value only.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation on how the [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) works in AngularJS.

You are injecting value in controllers, but the values won't be change, because requesting an injectable by it's ID always returns the same thing for the same ID.

You have to use,

```
app.value('value', {myValue: 0});
```

This is will return you an object named value, and you can change the value of 'myValue'.

Here is working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/swxrd4bc/1/